# Including 500 dummies with same prefix in plm regression without writing each separately?

Tags: r

I want to include 500 dummies in a regression using the plm package. The dummies are called var1, var2, ... var500, so only the number at the end changes. Is there any way to include them all together instead of having to write each variable separately in the formula?

Comment: One does wonder why you have dummy columns in the first place though.  Are these a combination of different categorical variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `as.formula` to construct a formula from string. Here is an example:

```
> paste0("var", 1:10)
 [1] "var1"  "var2"  "var3"  "var4"  "var5"  "var6"  "var7"  "var8"  "var9"  "var10"

> paste(paste0("var", 1:10), collapse = " + ")
[1] "var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + var10"

> paste("y~", paste(paste0("var", 1:10), collapse = " + "))
[1] "y~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + var10"

> as.formula(paste("y~", paste(paste0("var", 1:10), collapse = " + ")))
y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + 
    var10
```

More details can be found by typing `?as.formula` in the R console.